# Imagemagick fit svg to canvas

Tags: shell, image-processing, command-line, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I'm looking for ImageMagick command to fit my SVG to viewable image

This is now how my SVG looks like

[image]

I want to removed this empty spaces like this:

[image]

I'm looking for a similar functionality of `Inkspace's Resize page to drawing or selection`

[image]

Comment: ImageMagick is a raster image processor - it wants to work with bitmaps, not SVG files. Do you want to make your SVG into a raster/bitmap file? If so, please provide a link to your SVG file instead of a PNG file.

Comment: So its impossible to achive this with ImageMagic? This is my svg https://gist.github.com/lekishvili/2104bf6b8104335d5ba2

Comment: Huh? The SVG you link to doesn't have any extraneous blue lines like you show. You can trim any surrounding spare white space with ImageMagick though using `convert image.svg -trim result.png` if that is what you mean?

Comment: It does not have blue lines, that lines shows that i have up and down white spaces. I dont want to convert it to png, Tried this command to convert 14.svg -trim -repage 1.svg it returns svg but inside inside is base64 not paths check this gist please https://gist.github.com/lekishvili/bfffdb950477e63259e2

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't believe ImageMagick can create vector files like you wish.

Comment: I see, what command line tools i can use to achive such result?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe ImageMagick is able to give you a vector result - it converts everything internally to bitmaps as it is a raster image processor in essence.

However, it can tell you the geometry of your image and also the "trim box" which is the minimum enclosing box - maybe you can use that somehow to *"rebase"* your vector image's coordinates or viewport.

So, if you run this:

```
convert image.svg -format "%g %@" info:
100x100+0+0 93x63+4+19
```

it tells you that your image is 100x100 and that the "trim box" is 93x63 pixels and starts at coordinates [4,19]. I'll draw that on for you:

```
convert -stroke red -fill none image.svg -draw "rectangle 4,19 97,82" result.jpg
```

[image]